# Expressing overlap between two spinors as an integral and a sum

Tags: quantum-spin, spinors, many-body, quantum-chemistry

I was trying to go through some material involving the [Hartree–Fock  method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) for tackling the many electron problem. In most resources, namely in Lucjan Piela (pg 334) that we can the overlap between two spinors, with respect to an one-electron operator $\hat{h}$ can be given as $$\int d\tau_{1}\phi_{i}^{*}(1)\hat{h}\phi_{j}(1)$$
Where $d\tau_{1}$ represents collectively the 3 space and 1 spin coordinate. Now, apparently this can be further seperated into the following, given $\hat{h}$ does not act on the spin part:

$$\sum_{\sigma_{1}}\int dV_{1}\phi_{i}^{*}(1)\hat{h}\phi_{j}(1)$$

Where now, the integration is over the space coordinates and the summation is over the spin coordinates. I cannot understand how this was performed. Any help would be appreciated.